# DocuSign returnURL with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, docusignapi

Is there a way to modify the returnURL name-value pairs that our application receives back from DocuSign?

For example, if a user declines to sign, we get '?event=decline' as the name-value pair appended to the returnURL (http://foo.com/?event=decline). However, Drupal really really really dislikes the '?'. Even though i set ?event=decline as a menu item, the page will not display

Neither clean URLs (enabled/disabled) nor path aliasing, nor hook_url_inbound_alter has any effect on this

Does anyone know a way to change this in the DocuSign API or create a workaround in Drupal 7?

Comment: Can't change this on the DocuSign end, the fix will have to be through Drupal.  Can you not parse/edit the string afterwards?

Comment: Drupal will not parse a query string. I can do it with jQuery, but it is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of ways to do this but i settled on the following method:

1) I created a new menu item, $items['docusign'] in the hook_menu.
2) I appended that menu item to the returnURL, e.g., http://foo.com/docusign.
3) I created a page callback for the above menu item.
4) I then switched on $_GET['event'] and returned a form based upon that value.

Working well.

This can also probably be done through mod_rewrite in .htacces